# my form's action is being overridden but can't tell where

Tags: html, forms, action

on form submit button click (I tried form submit event as well)

I change form's action using

```
$form.attr('action', url);
```

Then I see if action is indeed changed

```
    url = $form.attr('action');
    alert(url);
```

Then I submit, but server sees different address requested...

```
    $form.submit();
```

Any idea where my form's action could be overwritten?

Comment: And $form is in the same scope? What does the developertools tab on networkrequests tell you?

Comment: yes $form is in the same scope, this is for ie8 compatability fix and I'm having hard time finding network requests tab;;

Comment: I just installed fiddler, and it shows, indeed url is overwritten...

Comment: Is it the original url?

Comment: no. form has no initial action attribute set.

Comment: oh.. I had "submit" event handler in encompassing backbone view. and I think event bubbled up there... Thanks! rene